# How to join columns from the same table in a SQL query to show them as one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just have a quick question about how to do something, but also about whether or not this is even possible in the first place. I've tried to find an answer online, but got no success.

I'll create a very simplified scenario that's not necessarily what I want to do precisely, but it's a pretty good example. Let's say that I have this table

```
Users
----------------------------------------------
| ID | FirstName | LastName | Username | ... |
|----|-----------|----------|----------|-----|
|   1| John      | Doe      | jdoe     | ... |
|   2| James     | Smith    | jsmith   | ... |
|   3| Jane      | Fisher   | jfisher  | ... |
|   x| ...       | ...      | ...      | ... |
----------------------------------------------
```

Let's say that I want to create a query to show only the FirstName and LastName, but as a full name.

I could do:

```
SELECT Users.FirstName, Users.LastName
FROM Users
WHERE ID > 2
```

What I want however is something that would give me FirstName and LastName as one column that I'd present like this:

```
(Users.FirstName, Users.LastName) AS 'Full Name'
```

Therefore, I'd get something like:

```
Users
---------------------------------------
| ID | Full Name     | Username | ... |
|----|---------------|----------|-----|
|   1| John Doe      | jdoe     | ... |
|   2| James Smith   | jsmith   | ... |
|   3| Jane Fisher   | jfisher  | ... |
|   x| ...           | ...      | ... |
---------------------------------------
```

Of course, in my real query, I'd be joining a bit more than just 2 columns,  but I think you get the point. So is this possible? If so, how can I do it.

Comment: `SELECT Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName as [Full Name]
FROM Users
WHERE ID > 2`  Well, the '[' are for sql server, not sure in other rdbms...

Comment: Also, I'd be using more than one table and using JOIN's eventually. I'm just saying in case it may be an issue.

Comment: Oh wow OK, that's a lot more simple than I thought... Thank you very much.

Comment: I've changed the tags. You are asking a SQL question on MySQL. Your environment (HeidiSQL) is not important when you merely want to know how to write the query. And you don't want joins explained either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT first_name + ' ' + last_name as full_name from users
```

in Oracle

```
SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name full_name from users
```

edit: maybe if you are having data type issues - you could force it to think it's a string - something like

```
SELECT '' + first_name + ' ' + last_name from users
```

Comment: Oh wow OK, that's a lot more simple than I thought... Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok so for some reason it doesn't work. I've tried using FirstName and LastName in my actual database to practice.

I've done:

SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS 'full_name'
FROM Usernames

Yet, all it gives me is a column named full_name as intended, but filled with 0's.

Comment: @G. Langlois: You are using MySQL. `+` means: add two numbers. Another DBMS would throw an error because the strings don't contain numbers, so the implicit conversion fails. MySQL, however, brashly converts to 0.

Comment: @Randy: `+` for string concatenation is non-standard. The standard operator is `||`. `+` is used in T-SQL and maybe some other SQL dialects. Most DBMS should use `||`. MySQL doesn't support either of the two. (I've gathered from the HeidiSQL tag that the OP uses MySQL.)

Answer (score 1):

You are using MySQL. While the standard string concatenation operator is `||`, it doesn't work with MySQL. Use the function `CONCAT_WS`:

```
select concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname)
from mytable;
```

(You could also use the function `CONCAT`, but I prefer `CONCAT_WS` in this situation.)

Here is the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws